# Saving NSManagedContext on another thread

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a core data object which is created on main thread of app (UI Queue), I want to update this object inside a closure which gets called after specific event , like a callback, can I access this object directly inside the closure ? While this be treated like a different thread ? I want to able to save the object to core data.

Answer (score 0):

Use one NSManagedObjectContext per thread. Pass the NSManagedObjectID, which is thread safe, and fetch the object again from your thread context.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your CoreData object in a closure using:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    (your update func) 
}
```

with this you are performing your action on main thread